# Winnovative Excel C# Read Text of cell

Tags: c#, excel, winnovative

i'm using Winnovative Excel Library for .NET and i'm able to read the value/text of a cell using this:

```
var cellText = firstWorksheet["A2"].Text;
```

But i'm not able to read the "raw text" if the cell is numeric or has a datetime value, I know I can see the value in:

```
var cellText = firstWorksheet["A2"].Value;
```

But this gives me {15/01/2017 12:00:00 a. m.} and I need the real string in file (15/01/2017)

Someone have used this third party library?

Comment: Is there a function similar to `Date()` to get the value?

Comment: No, there is no a Date() function, I need the original string in the file, for example if there is a "1" in the excel file, I need read "1" and Value and Text gives me "1.0" (I suppose tha it's a numeric cell) if there is a "01/01/2017" I need to read "01/01/2017" and not a DateTime value

Comment: From your statement: _But this gives me {15/01/2017 12:00:00 a. m.} and I need the real string in file (15/01/2017)_... Could you not simply read this in as text or convert the `cellText` variable `toString()` then simply split the string on spaces and grab the first value?

Comment: I mean, I need the real value of the cell, the date value it´s a example, I need read "15-JAN-2017" or "15-01-2017" or "15/01/2017", and for numeric values: "1" not "1.0" "5" not "5.0"

Answer (score 0):

If `firstWorksheet["A2"].Value` returns a `Datetime`, you could do something like:

```
celltext = celltext.ToShortDateString();
```

If not, try converting to `DateTime` `firstWorksheet["A2"].Value` and repeat step 1.